# Does fixing a Fusion Drive using 'diskutil resetFusion' destroy the BOOTCAMP partition

Tags: bootcamp, imac, fusion-drive

I have a 2015 iMac 27" retina whose Fusion Drive split into separate drives whilst attempting to fix a partition table issue prior to upgrading to macOS Big Sur.

I have a fully functioning BOOTCAMP partition with Windows 10 on the HDD drive.

If I run `diskutil resetFusion` to rejoin the Fusion Drive's SSD and HDD, will it destroy my BOOTCAMP partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all partitions on the SSD and HDD are destroyed by running `diskutil resetFusion`.

This is explained clearly after running the command; when it asks for confirmation.